# Dynamically hide rows in a range if cell above range is empty

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to hide rows in a range if the cell above the range is empty. Once the empty cell has a value, the row below it needs to become visible for data entry. As I move down or up in the range, there should always be only one row visible below the filled-in row for data entry. I have seen similar questions posted, but I have not seen the answer to dynamically hide/unhide rows based on row above. I started with the code below, but I am not familiar with "ByVal Target As Range" routines. Any assistance is much appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = Target.Row To Target.Row + Target.Rows.Count - 1
        If Cells(i - 1, Target.Column).Value = "" Then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the address of the range where you want this applied (e.g. `A2:AlastRow`)?

Comment: The address is A50:D100; Since A50 is currently empty, that row should always be visible.

Comment: What exactly must be populated for the next row to become visible? Just `A50` or `A50:D50` for row 51 to become visible?

Comment: If A50 <>0, then row 51 is visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A Worksheet Change: Show Hide Row Below

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const TARGET_RANGE As String = "A50:A100"
    
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = Me.Range(TARGET_RANGE)
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(trg, Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim icell As Range
    
    For Each icell In irg.Cells
        If Len(CStr(icell.Value)) = 0 Then
            icell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
'            ' A bit different idea:
'            Me.Range(icell.Offset(1), trg.Cells(trg.Cells.Count)) _
'                .EntireRow.Hidden = True
'            Exit For
        Else
            icell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            icell.Offset(1).Select
        End If
    Next icell
    
End Sub
```